# Handle negative time in TimeSpan

Tags: c#, rows, timespan

How to handle negative time in `TimeSpan`?

If the time negative should `00:00:00`. This is the code I tried but does not work at the `if` statement

```
RepGrd.Rows[ii].Cells[0].Value = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[j][1];

RepGrd.Rows[ii].Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1];

RepGrd.Rows[ii].Cells[2].Value = totalTime;
allow = TimeSpan.Parse("03:30:00");
allow = totalTime - allow;
if  (allow == -allow)
{
    RepGrd.Rows[ii].Cells[3].Value = "00:00:00";
}
else
{
    //TimeSpan allow_LateSet = TimeSpan.ParseExact("03:30", "HH:mm", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    RepGrd.Rows[ii].Cells[3].Value = allow;
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "If the time negative should 00:00:00". It would be a lot easier to help you if you provided a [mcve] - I very much doubt that all the row/cell parts are relevant, and they mean we can't easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? what should be at `Cell[3]` ? `3:30` if its less than `totalTime` and `0:00` if not? or the substraction and `0:00` if negative?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you should change the following (which will only ever be true if `allow` is `0`):

```
if  (allow == -allow)`
```

To this (which detects if allow is less than or equal to 00:00:00

```
if (allow <= TimeSpan.Zero)
```

Or, more simply:

```
allow = TimeSpan.Parse("03:30:00");

RepGrd.Rows[ii].Cells[3].Value = totalTime > allow ? totalTime - allow : TimeSpan.Zero;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement doesn't do what you describe you want:

```
allow = totalTime - allow;
if  (allow == -allow)
```

This is only true if `allow` would be 0!

If you want to know if `totalTime` is greater than the maximum allowed. I would expect something like

```
if (totalTime > allow)
```

Of course, you cannot use that in your code because you overwrite your `allow` variable, so I suggest you use a separate variable to calculate the difference between `totalTime` and `allow` *if you need that difference*.

Comment: @SabriBamerhool that's too bad. Then you have to give more information about what actually happens, what you actually expect and how you changed your code. Of course just changing your `if` statement will not work, but I explained that already...

Comment: @SabriBamerhool please explain what *you* mean by "does not work": any errors (please specify)? Not the output you expect (what did you expect, what did you see)?